# How to make Cuttleflish open Chrome when computer connects to the internet

Tags: google-chrome, cuttlefish

I like to use Google Chrome (with the Tweetdeck for Chrome app) as my Twitter app, and I also watch Youtube on it. Other then that, I just use Firefox for everything else.

I JUST installed Cuttleflish, and was wondering how to make Google Chrome open when my computer connects to the internet (after startup.)

Can someone please help me figure out how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly cuttlefish only provides a "connected to WiFi-Network" stimulus only at the moment. There is ongoing work on network-specific stimuli, so the best solution I can think of is to wait for the next release.

Comment: I think thats what I want, actually. How would I do that?

Comment: Never mind... I got it